# Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i trying to run this code by pdo

```
db::query("SELECT v.id, v.rel_x, v.rel_y FROM p_villages v WHERE v.field_maps_id=3
            AND ISNULL(v.player_id) AND (v.rel_x >= ?,?,?,? AND v.rel_x <= ?,?,?,?)
            AND (v.rel_y >= ?,?,?,? AND v.rel_y <= ?,?,?,?)
            AND v.rand_num > 0 ORDER BY v.rand_num LIMIT 1",array(1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3));
```

but i found this error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) \
```

so, i need the output query like `SELECT v.id, v.rel_x, v.rel_y FROM p_villages v WHERE v.field_maps_id=3 AND ISNULL(v.player_id) AND (v.rel_x >= 1,2,3,4 AND v.rel_x <= 1,2,3,4) AND (v.rel_y >= 1,2,3,4 AND v.rel_y <= 1,2,3,4) AND v.rand_num > 0 ORDER BY v.rand_num LIMIT 1` and in the parameters i want to pass each parameter of those parameters which here is 16

what should i do ?

Comment: Your SQL syntax is wrong. You cannot apply the greater than/less than operators to more than 1 column on each side of the operator, so for example `v.rel_x >= ?,?,?,?` is meaningless, and will give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

this: `v.rel_y <= ?,?,?,?`

looks weird.

Bound parameters have to be self contained, you cannot build the right or left part of a comparison by more than one.

i.e, if you mean to say `x >= 5.1`, you cannot put `x >= ?.?` and pass 2 parameters to the pdo statement.
You would then have to pass `x >= ?` and then `bindValue(5.1);`

Comment: so, i need the output query like 

`SELECT v.id, v.rel_x, v.rel_y FROM p_villages v WHERE v.field_maps_id=3
            AND ISNULL(v.player_id) AND (v.rel_x >= 1,2,3,4 AND v.rel_x <= 1,2,3,4)
            AND (v.rel_y >= 1,2,3,4 AND v.rel_y <= 1,2,3,4)
            AND v.rand_num > 0 ORDER BY v.rand_num LIMIT 1`

and in the parameters i want to pass each parameter of those parameters which here is 16

Comment: @BodyLove I think you need to revise your sql syntax. You cannot use numbers separated by a comma like this in a comparison. Plus it just doesn't make sense anyway, why would you use 1,2,3,4 instead of 4 and 1 only?